# Python Password Validation: Unable to use constants from string library in regex

Tags: python, regex, string

```
def check_password(pw):
    global reason
    while True:
        if not re.search(string.ascii_lowercase,pw):
            flag = False
            reason = get_error(4)
            break

        elif not re.search(string.ascii_uppercase, pw):
            flag = False
            reason = get_error(1)
            break

        elif not re.search(string.digits, pw):            
            flag = False
            reason = get_error(2)
            break
        elif not re.search(string.punctuation, pw):          
            flag = False
            reason = get_error(3)
            break
        else:
            flag = True
            print("Valid Password") 
            break
        return flag

flag = False
min_length = 5

#password = input("Please enter your password:")
password = getpass.getpass("Enter Password:")

if len(password) >= min_length:
    check_password(password)
    print(password)
    if flag == True:
        print("Valid Password!")
    else:
        print(reason)
else:           
    print("Your password is not long enough.")
```

Here I am using regex to validate a password. I was successful if I hardcode the pattern "[A-Z]", "[0-9]", but now if I use string library  constants, I am getting the message from the 1st check, irrespective of anything else wrong in the password.

Can you tell me where I am wrong, syntactically or semantically?

Comment: With `[a-z]` you check if any of the characters from `a` to `z` is in the string. With `string.ascii_lowercase` you check if `'abcdefghijklmnoprstuvwxyz'` is in the string. You might want to use `'[' + string.ascii_lowercase + ']'` (or just keep `[a-z]`).

Comment: `return flag` is unreachable, `check_password` is returning `None`. You don't actually need loop there, remove it.

Comment: Thanks @Matthias.
 But how can I check for special Characters? I dont wanna hard code them

Comment: thanks for the loop edit @Guy! :-)

Comment: See [Reference - Password Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48345922/3600709)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constants only contain chunks of characters, but you want to create character classes out of them. That means you need to enclose all of them with `[` and `]`. Also, you need to make sure some characters are escaped (`^`, `-`, `]` and `\`), otherwise the punctuation regex will not be matching what you expect.

So, you need to replace `string.ascii_lowercase` with `f"[{string.ascii_lowercase}]"`, `string.ascii_uppercase` with `f"[{string.ascii_uppercase}]"`, `string.digits` with `f"[{string.digits}]"`, `string.punctuation` with `f"[{string.punctuation.replace("\\", "\\\\").replace("-", r"\-").replace("^", r"\^").replace("]", r"\]")}]"`.

If your Python environment is older than 3.7 and does not support string interpolation, use `str.format`, e.g. `if not re.search(r"[{}]".format(string.ascii_lowercase),pw)` and so on.

Comment: I was afraid to use [ ] , as I thought that would probably turn it into a list, and i was getting a lot of errors during the function call.

Comment: @Jay with the guidance from me you can now use `[...]`  without fear. There are no lists here, just character sets. Special chars could give you trouble but now you know which of them need escaping.